# Connect App Not Returning Results , SHA 256 HASH

Tags: api, connected-apps, sap

I Have created a Connected App in SF Sandbox. It is to be utilized by SAP CPI to authorize and fetch the results from SAP.

We are able to authorize and fetch records ,using SF stnadard API, from Postman but when we are trying to Authorize and fetch results from SAP CPI it is giving the below mentioned error:-

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
The call to the token endpoint failed with HTTP return code 400 (Bad Request). 
Please check the configuration of the credential 'Salesforce_Oauth_Cred': 
Problem during requesting the refresh token for the OAuth2 Authorization Code Credential Salesforce_Oauth_Cred: 
HTTP request with token URL 'https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token', client Id 'xxxxxxxx', client secret SHA256 hash 'zzzzzzzzzz', code SHA 256 hash 'ssssssssssss', and scope 'refresh_token offline_access' failed. 
HTTP response code: 400, 
Error Message: 
{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"scope parameter not supported"}
</response>
```

Also,the client secert here mentioned above(zzzzzzzzzz) is not the client secert generated from Connected app. But when we use any convertor to convert the client secert genrated from connected App using "SHA 256 hash" it gets converted to "zzzzzzzzzz".

How can we resolve this issue.
Is it something related to the "SHA 256 Hash" algorith/certification which we can provide in Connected app or Salesforce or do we need to send any parameter from SAP in the API request if it is converting the Client secert to a value using "SHA 256 hash" algorith.

Comment: @all: Did you find any solution to this?